# jQuery slider redirect on 4th click

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm using the jQuery Superslides plugin here: http://dougalpaterson.com.s69396.gridserver.com
And I want to redirect the user to the main website on the 4th click of the .next arrow (after the last slide), rather than looping through the slideshow again.

I've managed to add the address to the href using this js:

```
$('#slides').superslides({
  animation: 'fade'   
});
var clicked=0;
$('a.next').on('click', function (e) {
clicked++;

if (clicked >= 3) {
    clicked = 0;
    $("a.next").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
} else {
    e.preventDefault();
}

});
```

But when I click on the arrow, it doesn't send the user to the URL. I think this may be because of the:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

In the original plugin.

How can I remove the preventDefault, so that I send the user to my desired URL?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you suspect it's the preventDefault() method which prevents the default behaviour of the link (which would be to send the user to the href). So what you could do (if sending the user to some URL is all you want on the fourth click) is just change:

```
$("a.next").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
```

to:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
```

This would redirect the user instead of setting the href of the link.

---

This would work if you pressed the .next-link four times in a row. It would also work if you pushed this sequence though: .next->.prev->.next->.prev->.next->.prev->.next which might not be what you'd want (as it counts any clicks on the .next-link no matter where in the slideshow the user actually is).

So a better solution might be to actually check if the user is actually on the last slide when clicking the .next-link, and if so: redirect the user.

Comment: Very cool - thanks so much - I used your first answer for now, but will update it to the second solution when I have more time.